# Excel Conditional Formatting - Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to put some conditional formatting into a spreadsheet but I have become stuck, I have three things I need to check:

1. Does the name in column A match with one in D
2. Is the date in column E today or earlier
3. Is the date in column G today or later

If all of these conditions are met then the corresponding cell in column A will change colour.

Here's whats in the table:

- There is a list of staff in column A
- If they are out of office at any time during the week their name will be in column D
- Column E is the start of their time off
- Column G is the end of their time off

So far I can only get it to highlight if the names match, I'm struggling to add the other conditions even after Googling for hours:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,$D:$D,1,FALSE)))
```

I also tried this, to no effect:

```
=AND($A2=$D:$D,$E1<TODAY(),$G1>TODAY())
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. I tried the following formula and it appears to work:

```
=AND(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,$D:$E,2,FALSE)<TODAY(),FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,$D:$G,4,FALSE)>TODAY(),FALSE))
```

The result of this is:

[image]

Comment: I found this one works, but if it has today's date in E or G it does not highlight. Any suggestions?

Comment: You used `<` and `>` in your attempt, so I copied that. Replacing it with `<=` and `>=` will include the values in E and G as start and end dates.

Comment: Thank you @jsheeran I was trying it backwards `=<`

Answer (score 1):

@jsheeran's answer will work. However, if you apply it to many cells, it could become slow due to the VLOOKUP. INDEX/MATCH is a one to one replacement for VLOOKUP and it is faster, more adaptable, and doesn't break if you were to insert a column between D and E.

```
=AND(
    IFERROR(
        INDEX($E:$E, MATCH($A1,$D:$D,0))<=TODAY(), 
        FALSE
    ), 
    IFERROR(
        INDEX($G:$G, MATCH($A1,$D:$D,0))>=TODAY(), 
        FALSE
    )
)
```